# Show modal with video when loading page with option to click the button to open the same modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I will try to be as fast as possible ... I was able to set up a beautiful video modal by clicking a button using bootstrap, css, html and js. But my current intention is that when opening the page for the first time, this same modal will open with the video and if the person closes this modal, they will have the option to click this button to open it again ... I'm trying to do This however I am not succeeding. Would anyone have a tip?

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- BootsTrap library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script> <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="body-flex container-fluid d-flex flex-column flex-fill">
          <div class="row flex-column flex-fill">
        <div class="col-12 col text-center flex-fill"> <!-- change btn position here in "txt-center" -->
          <h1></h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary video-btn custombtnsize" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ld2Vn8ouxqY" data-target="#myModal"> Ajuda </button>  <!-- Button trigger modal , you can use btn-lg to responsive large btn -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>        
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">  <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video"  allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { // Gets the video src from the data-src on each button
    var $videoSrc;  
    $('.video-btn').click(function() {
      $videoSrc = $(this).data( "src" );
    });
    console.log($videoSrc); // when the modal is opened autoplay it  
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0" );  // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
    })
    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) { // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
      $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc);     // a poor man's stop video
    }) 
  });   // document ready  
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style> 
  body {margin: 0,2rem;}
  .body-flex {
     min-height:100vh;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
  }
  .flex-fill {
     flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
  .custombtnsize {
      width: 120px !important;
      height: 50px !important;
  }
  .modal-dialog {
        max-width: 800px;
        margin:  30px auto;
    }
  .modal-body {
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
  }
  .close {
    position:absolute;
    right:-30px;
    top:0;
    z-index:999;
    font-size:2rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:1;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger modal event on document ready:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { // Gets the video src from the data-src on each button
              var $videoSrc = $('.video-btn').data( "src" );
              $('#myModal').modal();

              console.log($videoSrc); // when the modal is opened autoplay it  
              $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0" );  // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
              })
              $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) { // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
                $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc);     // a poor man's stop video
              }) 
            });   // document ready
```